# Magento2 Thai S3 extension for S3 Bucket getting 403 error

Tags: magento2

Magento2.3.2 I am using below extension for S3 Bucket.

> https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3

The issue I am facing is when I try to upload images from admin to a product I get 403 forbidden error & image doesn't get uploaded  to S3 Bucket.

I am in a big trouble due to this, can some guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read readme , this module is not yet supported on Magento 2.3 because of : "braking changes"

Comment: Please read readme , this module is not yet supported on Magento 2.3

because of :

"braking changes"